# Why is the behavior of nested class different between different ways of class declaration?

Tags: ruby, class

Why doesn't `c.f()` below work as `b.f()`? I'd like to use the `class A::C`-way to declare a nested class for avoiding too many indentations.

```
class A
  CONSTANT = 1
end

class A
  class B
    p self # => A::B
      def f
        print CONSTANT, "\n"
      end
  end
end

class A::C
  p self # => A::C
  def f
    print CONSTANT, "\n"
  end
end

b = A::B.new
b.f() # => 1
c = A::C.new
c.f() # => `f': uninitialized constant A::C::CONSTANT (NameError)
```

Comment: "Why doesn't c.f() work as b.f() as I expected?" might not be good phrase. The behaviour is due to specification of Ruby. I'd re-phrase like "Is there any good way to declare nested classes avoiding many indentations?" I know that indentation itself is not obligation but not-following-coding-style looks ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it in one line using semicolon:

```
class A; class C
  ...
end end
```

Comment: Thanks!!. umm... looks nice. so far this sounds best. pls let me wait for some comments or answers from others

Comment: As far as I checked, no libraries bundled with Ruby are taking this coding style. No much people feel heavy nesting/indents are troublesome?

Comment: Probably they use an IDE with indenting functions. I don't know.

Comment: yup, maybe. I also use IDE sometime, vim sometime. even with IDE, too much nesting class/module cause heavy indent and it leads to less good looking to grab begin/do-end block chunk (sorry for my poor expression in English). 'two' column indents accelerate it. As for Python, it is much better because 'four' is common and mismatch indents are syntax error. any way many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this by prefixing the constant with `A::`

```
class A
  CONSTANT = 1
end

class A
  class B
    def f
      puts A::CONSTANT
    end
  end
end

class A::C
  def f
    puts A::CONSTANT
  end
end

b = A::B.new
b.f() #=> 1
c = A::C.new
c.f() #=> 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that way once but... in A::C, if I'd like to use many constants or class methods decleared in A, we need to prepend many 'A::' for those. and when name of class 'A' is changed, I need to change all 'A::' in 'A::C' to new name. It might cause some trouble... (mistakes..)